# How does nifi generate documentation?

Tags: java, scala, documentation, apache-nifi

Looking through Apache nifi's source, I see that they generate their documentation using @ symbols at the beginning of the code. [Here's an example for reference.](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-email-bundle/nifi-email-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/email/ExtractEmailHeaders.java) How is the documentation generated from these lines? Is this possible using scala?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@` symbols are syntax for [Java Annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/), which Apache NiFi uses to mark up extension components for generating documentation.

NiFi documentation is generated by the [nifi-documentation](https://github.com/apache/nifi/tree/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-framework-bundle/nifi-framework/nifi-documentation) sub-project, part of the NiFi framework.  You can follow the details in the [DocGenerator.generate](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/rel/nifi-1.3.0/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-framework-bundle/nifi-framework/nifi-documentation/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/documentation/DocGenerator.java#L59) method.  There are some unit tests in the nifi-documentation project that will help you run through it.

I'm not very familiar with Scala, but I believe you can read/write Java annotations.